# Ask init.....not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-iam, alexa-skills-kit, init

I've been following the instructions for installing the ASK CLI, but I'm stuck at the $ask init step.

I get the prompt that says, "Please create a new profile or overwrite the existing profile."

When I select "default" I see the options, "Skip AWS credential for ask-cli" and "Use the AWS environment variables", but it won't let me select either one...I'm back at the command prompt.

When I select "Create new", It asks for my new profile name, but I'm back at the command prompt instead of being able to answer this question.

In all cases, no browser window ever pops open to let me enter my IAM credentials.

And, I've tried the "--no-browser" option, and no web address ever appears for me to follow.

I'm stumped....any help is so much appreciated!

Comment: What instructions have you been following? Please edit your question and insert a link.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turns out ask-cli didn't play nice with the latest version of node (10.x.x) so I downgraded it to the latest stable release (8.12.0) and reinstalled ask-cli and it worked.

I am on a windows 10 machine.